# Show New Products in a new page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-list, product-collection

have created a 'new page' as 'latest products' and i want to show all the products in this page but sorted 'datewise' i.e. new first ..
i got from google was to use this code

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
  <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
  <action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action> 
  </block>
  </reference>
```

but with this approach i have to set the product attribute " New from Date" .
in 'backend' i have a table where i have products with "Date Created" column
is it possible to pull products from that table, sorted 'datewise' and show in the 'new page' ??
if yes,
How ??
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by logging into the admin panel . A "new page" means a page under `Admin Panel -> CMS -> Pages`, you can select the page, edit the content and add a widget called "Catalog new product list".

[image: the catalog new product list widget]

There are times when an approach of editing files and writing code is needed as it is more powerful, but you should try to use Magento's build in functionality when possible, since it will be more tested that stuff you will write and will save you time;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better `to create new block` class which is extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` class.

Then on new class `join product collection` with `your custom table` using join query.

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Block extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New{
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $table = 'Your_Table';
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
           /*  ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              ) */
            ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1);
             $collection->getSelect()->join(array('AliasnameTable' => $table),
    'AliasnameTable.prodduct_id = e.entity_id', array('date_created'))->setOrder('AliasnameTable.date_created','desc');


        return $collection;
    }

}
```

**xml code:**

**Create a custom module and  custom block type**

```
<global>
 <blocks>
    <custommodule>
    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Block</class>
    </custommodule>
</blocks>
</global>
```

**Then change** from  `catalog/product_new` to `custommodule/new` .

[See how to create Custom module](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)

Comment: i will try this as well

Comment: @Amit how can we get the collection within the layered navigation so that the collection is properly filtered?